# LINQ flexible data filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

In my table I have a couple of `DateTime` fields:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources), Name = "Year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public string CustomerDesc { get; set; }
    public string ProductDesc { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }

    public double Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

when the user looks for some records, he should be able to use a "flexible" way to search them, i.e. for OrderDate:

> 01/03/2018 // exactly this day
>
> 01/03      // 1st March of any year
>
> 03/2018    // any day of March 2018

should returns the records where OrderDate is the 1st March 2018, all records where OrderDate is 1st March (any year) or where OrderDate is March 2018 (any day).

I know it's not really a "date" query - it looks like to a string compare.
Hence, I tried the most obvious way:

```
var records = from s in _context.Orders.AsNoTracking() select s;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchOrderDate)) records = records.Where(x => x.OrderDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Contains(searchOrderDate));
```

but of course it complains about LINQ cannot use the `ToString()` method.

The ugly way is to do this at model level, adding a field that stores the
string version of the date, and perform the search on this one.

Is there something better to do?

### EDIT

After the useful comments, the question is about performing string comparison (i.e. `Contains()`) on `DateTime` fields. This because the request is not really related to a *date* comparison.

Comment: You could translate `searchOrderDate` to 2 `DateTime` values (e.g. `03/2018` translates to `1/3/2018` and `31/3/2018`), and you query becomes a `.Where(x => x.OrderDate >= startDate && x.OrderDate <= endDate)`

Comment: Alternatively you could translate `searchOrderDate` to 3 `int?` for `day`, `month` and `year`, and then you build the query depending if the values have a value - e.g. `if (day.HasValue) { records = records.Where(x => OrderDate.Date == day.Value);` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke it might work, but what if the user enters only "03"? I should return records with the date set to March (any day, any year) and records with the date set to 3rd (any months, any year). It's exactly the behavior of the `.Contains()` method of `String`

Comment: A value of just `"03"` should probably be invalid - what would that mean? - any dates with the date part being 3, or the month part being 3? But if you do want that to be valid, then you would set `day=3` and `month=3` so the `if (month.HasValue) { ... }` is also executed

Comment: You would also have to ensure users send a 4 digit date, and of course you would need to validate it all before actually executing the query (e.g. `month` <= 12 etc).

Comment: As said "03" should be considered valid like described. I agree it doesn't really make much sense... - the question might boils down to: "how to perform String compares on `DateTime` fields?"

Comment: Therefore, you will also want to search all years containing `03` as well which makes it a bit more difficult